# ELF Imports and Exports

Tags: shared-libraries, elf

i know we have `.dynsym` and `.symtab`, how can i differentiate between imports and exports , like  in pe in windows, imports and exports are in data directories, is it and equivalent in elf?

Comment: Of interest: [What is an ELF Export?](https://www.m4b.io/elf/export/binary/analysis/2015/05/25/what-is-an-elf-export.html) Note: Will not post this as an answer as it is only a link.

Answer (score 6):

> how can i differentiate between imports and exports

Easy: any symbol in the dynamic symbol table (in `.dynsym`) for which `.st_shndx == SHN_UNDEF` (references special `UND` section) is an import, and every other symbol is defined and exported.

Note that `.symtab` doesn't matter and can be completely stripped -- the dynamic loader never looks at it.